# How to create object methods in JSContext

Tags: javascript, ios, objective-c, javascriptcore

I'm implementing JavascriptCore in an app. I've set up a `JSContext` and I'd like to be able to add some object methods to it. Ideally, what I'd like to be able to do in javascript is:

```
var titlefield = inputfield.new();
titlefield.text = "The title";
titlefield.color = red;
return titlefield;
```

Now, here's the `JSContext` I've set up:

```
- (id)init {
    self = [super init];

    [self evaluateScript:@"var inputfield = {}"];
    self[@"input"][@"new"] = ^() {
        CustomTextField *inputfield = [[CustomTextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(6, 0, 100,48)];
        return inputfield;
    };
```

What I don't know - and can't seem to be able to find any documentation about - is how I plug other methods into this newly created object. Any ideas?